# Which word is the head of the phrase "somewhere there"?

Tags: adverbs, phrases, adjuncts

Robocop's catchphrase is

> somewhere there is a crime  happening

If the sentence was just *a crime is happening* it would be unproblematic for me:
*a crime* would be a noun phrase in the function of a subject,
*is happening* would be a verb phrase in the function of a predicate.

Now in *somewhere there*, both words are adverbs , so it has to be an adverb phrase and it's function is a subject.

My problem is which of them is the head of the adverb phrase, because both appear to me as if they could.

**remark**

As it turned out , my question is based on wrong assumptions *somewhere there* in *somewhere there is a crime happening* is not a phrase.

Comment: Erm, you have that quote the wrong way. The quote is "Somewhere **there is** a crime happening", not ""Somewhere **there** a crime **is** happening". This makes all the difference to the answer!!!

Comment: ... because in the first sentence *there* would be the Subject of the sentence (and arguably a pronoun) and *somewhere* would be a locative Adjunct, but in the second sentence many modern grammars would classify *there* as a preposition (like *somewhere*), and *somewhere there* would be a preposition phrase functioning as a locative Adjunct.

Comment: For the original quote [see this Google search here](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22somewhere+there+is+a+crime++happening%22&oq=%22somewhere+there+is+a+crime++happening%22&gs_l=serp.3..0i30k1l2j0i5i30k1.10552.14304.0.15629.4.4.0.0.0.0.130.336.3j1.4.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..0.4.335...0i8i30k1j0i7i30k1j0i7i5i30k1.j_ZmcK1ilvw)

Comment: 'there is a crime happening' is a pretty standard [existential clause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Existential_clause). It's got the adverb 'somewhere' preceding, but it could just as easily be moved to follow the clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Somewhere there is a crime happening.

In the sentence above from the Robocop films the word *somewhere* is functioning as a Locative Adjunct. Notice that it can appear either at the beginning or end of the clause:

- There is a crime happening somewhere.

Notice also that the word *there* cannot move with the word *somewhere*:

- *Is a crime  happening somewhere there.

This suggests that the word *there* is not part of this Locative Adjunct. If we look at the sentence above, it is easy to see that the main reason it is ungrammatical is because it does not have a Subject. This is because in the original example, the word *there* IS the Subject of the sentence as the data below indicates:

- There is a crime happening
- Is there a crime happening?
- There is a crime happening, isn't there?
- There is!

The second example above shows *there* inverting with the auxiliary verb to form a question, as a good Subject should. The third example shows the word *there* appearing in the question tag *isn't there* as we would expect (compare with ***He***'s happy, isn't **he?**) The fourth example shows the sentence reduced to a minimal Subject and Predicate. Because the word *is* constitutes the Predicate, the word *there* must be the Subject.

In response to the Original Question then, the answer is that *somewhere* and *there* do not form a  phrase in this sentence, and therefore neither one of them can be the Head of that phrase. *Somewhere* is functioning as  Locative Adjunct, whereas *there* is functioning as Subject.

Comment: Erm, any helpful advice from the downvoter? (I can't improve my answer without it!)

Answer (score 1):

Edit: As Araucaria pointed out, OP (and consequently I) misinterpreted the sentence for *Somwhere there a crime is happening*/*Somehwere there, there is a crime happening*, which, however, is not what the sentence says; so my below answer only applies to the other assumption, not to the original sentence.

I would argue that *there* is the head for the following reasons:

- It is semantically more prominent: the information that projects is that the crime happend *there*, and *somewhere* somewhat relativizes the specificness of this local information, but the crime still happend *there* and not just *somewhere*. So *somewhere* would be a modifier to *there* rather than *there* adding more information about *somehwere*, because the phrase as a whole has the meaning that the crime happend *there*.
- I can't think of a case where in English the head of the adverb phrase precedes its adverbal modifiers - nested adverb structures, just like adjective sturctures, are to my knowledge always left-branching, i.e. the modifiers occur to the left, so if the head was *somehwere* while the modifier is *there*, this would be a very unusual exception to this general pattern.

Comment: @Araucaria Oops, yes, you are of course right; I actually misinterpreted the sentence. I won't change my answer because yours already says everything, put I'll include a disclaimer saying that my answer only applies to the the other (wrong) assumption. Thanks for pointing it out.